# using eclipse instead of visual studio for cocos2d-x project

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, visual-studio

im using coco2d-x v 3.0  i made a new windows project to test it and it is working but when i try to build and run a project using this command `cocos run -p win32`
it is print this error [image]

it seem like it need visual studio to run but how can i build and run the project throw eclipse or any IDE i have tried to open it as project using eclipse in deterrent ways but not working it printed lots of errors what should i do ?

Answer (score -1):

Cocos2d-x v3 uses Visual Studio 2012.

http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Windows

Comment: This is a link only answer, and doesn't even directly answer the question. Link only answers are discouraged. You should flesh this out with more information and rationale for why it solves the problem and is still useful even if the link disappears.